# Cross domain communication from parent to child iFrame using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, parent-child

I need to pass data from a web page to an iFrame hosted in that web page. I used window.postMessage. however the iFrame does not receive the event.

Here is my code snippet.
Parent page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test event listener</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SendMsgToIFrame() {
    alert("In Parent window ");
    var myiframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    if (myiframe.contentDocument) {
        myiframe.contentDocument.postMessage('Post Message from Parent', '*');
    }
    else if (myiframe.contentWindow) {
        myiframe.contentWindow.postMessage('Post Message from Parent', '*');
    }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="SendMsgToIFrame()">Push to iframe</button>
<div id="iframeDiv">
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://localhost:50000/Receiver.htm" width="500" height="200" frameborder=10> 
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code snippet for Receiver.htm is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Got Text</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.attachEvent("onMessage", myhandler);

    function myhandler(mobj) {
        alert("I am in iFrame");
        var message = mobj.data;

        alert("data: " + message);
    }
</script>
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="text here" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

I am running the parent page on Tomcat (localhost:8080). The iFrame is running on my HTTP server I built using the httplistener. 
When I run the parent page and hit the button that generates the event, I do not get the alert "I am in iFrame". Looks like the iFrame is not receiving the event at all. What am I missing here? 
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some strange parts. You're using `attachEvent` where it's better to use `addEventListener` and you should probably post to `contentWindow`, not document.

Comment: I am using IE8.addEventListener will not work with IE8. AttachEvent is the correct method for IE8. I am posting to content window. My breakpoint reaches that line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code was this: 
    window.attachEvent("onMessage", myhandler)

onmessage should be all lower case.
Once I changed this line to the below, it worked.

```
window.attachEvent("onmessage", myhandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the answer here: [javascript cross domain iframe resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856783/javascript-cross-domain-iframe-resize)

And that link also has a link to sample working code on github.